# Unable to change the width of an ElevatedButton in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am unable to reduce the width of `ElevatedButton` even though I've put it inside a `SizedBox`.

Given below is my code:

```dart
SizedBox(
  width: 70.0,
  child: ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
      padding:
      EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40.0, vertical: 15.0),
      primary: Color(0xff78048e),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
      ),
    ),
    child: Text(
      "CLICK ME",
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: What is the parent of this widget

Answer (score 0):

you can set maximumSize property of the style which will change the size of the button

```
style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
             maximumSize: Size(maximumWidth,maximumHeight),
               padding:
                   EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40.0, vertical: 15.0),
               shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
               primary: Color(0xff78048e)),
```

Answer (score 0):

By default the minimum size of the elevated button is => Size(64, 36),  use Size.zero to make button with no minimum size

Also check out the parent widget, it may forces child to take up a lot of width

```
ElevatedButton(
               onPressed: () {},
               style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    minimumSize: Size.zero,
                   padding:
                       EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40.0, vertical: 15.0),
                   shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                       borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                   primary: Color(0xff78048e)),
               child: Text(
                 "CLICK ME",
                 style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
               ),
             ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using padding `EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40.0, vertical: 15.0),` which is forcing the button to have a large width.

Change

```dart
padding:  EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40.0, vertical: 15.0),
```

to

```dart
padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 10.0),
```

---

According to docs `ElevatedButton` has default minimum size of `Size(64, 36)`. You can change this by overriding the `minimumSize` property inside `style`.

Example:

```dart
ElevatedButton(
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
    horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 10.0),
    minimumSize: const Size(30, 20), //  Change this according to your requirement
  ),
  onPressed: () {},
  child: const Text("Click Me"),
),
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Let me know if this is what you wanted , if you have a different requirement, let me know, I'll work it out for you.